Decode custom encoding algorithm
I have the following custom encoding algorithm in Go (similar to Base64). Note that I didn't write the customEncode function, it has come from elsewhere so I can't modify it
func shuffle(input rune) rune {
    return input + 59
}

func customEncode(input []byte) string {
    inputLen := len(input)
    output := make([]rune, 0, inputLen*4/3*4)

    for i := 0; i < inputLen; i += 3 {
        chunk := uint32(0)
        for j := 0; j < 3; j++ {
            if i+j < inputLen {
                chunk |= uint32(input[i+j]) << (8 * (2 - j))
            }
        }

        for shift := 18; shift >= 0; shift -= 6 {
            group := (chunk >> shift) & 63
            output = append(output, shuffle(rune(group)))
        }
    }

    switch inputLen % 3 {
    case 1:
        output = output[:len(output)-2]
    case 2:
        output = output[:len(output)-1]
    }

    return string(output)
}


I'm trying to write a decoder for the encoder, and this is my attempt so far:
func unshuffle(input rune) rune {

    switch {
    case input > 96:
        return input - 59
    case input > 64:
        return input - 53
    case input > 47:
        return input - 46
    default:
        return input - 45
    }
}

func customDecode(encoded string) []byte {
    output := make([]byte, 0, len(encoded))
    for i := 0; i < len(encoded); i += 4 {
        chunk := uint32(0)
        for j := 0; j < 4 && i+j < len(encoded); j++ {
            chunk |= uint32(unshuffle(rune(encoded[i+j]))) << (18 - j*6)
        }

        output = append(output,
            byte((chunk>>16)&0xFF),
            byte((chunk>>8)&0xFF),
            byte(chunk&0xFF),
        )
    }
    
    if len(encoded)%4 == 3 {
        output = output[:len(output)-1]
    } else if len(encoded)%4 == 2 {
        output = output[:len(output)-2]
    }

    return output
}

This is my test code to check the validity of the output:
func TestEncoding(t *testing.T) {
    input := "Lorem ipsum"
    encoded := customEncode([]byte(input))

    decoded := customDecode(encoded)

    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("Encoded: %s", encoded))

    fmt.Println([]byte(input))
    fmt.Println(decoded)
    if !bytes.Equal([]byte(input), decoded) {
        t.Fail()
    }
}

//Encoded: H4xmNKoUOL_nRKo
//[76 111 114 101 109 32 105 112 115 117 109]
//[76 111 114 101 109 32 105 122 179 117 109]

As you can see from the test result, the output bytes are slightly different to the input bytes. I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong - but how can I fix my decoder to ensure that the output matches the input bytes?
Interestingly, if I use Lorem as the input string, the decoded bytes are correct.

Please consider rolling back that last edit; the question now makes little sense (as Shuffle, the thing you cannot change, has changed). Edits that add clarity etc are fine but significantly changing the question (particularly after accepting an answer) is [not recommended]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478).

I have not put any effort into understanding your algorithm; this is a quick answer based on an issue I spotted when glancing at the code (there may well be other issues!).
It looks like customEncode converts 3 bytes into 4 bytes (with each byte having a value between 0 and 63 - this is based on the &63) and then passes these values through shuffle. Lets test your shuffle function for these values:
func main() {
    for i := 0; i <= 63; i++ {
        processed := unshuffle(shuffle(rune(i)))
        if rune(i) != processed {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }
    }
}

This will output the following (playground):
0
1
2
3
12
13
14
15
16

So it appears you have a bug. Looking at your shuffle function I note values over 11 are increased by 53 (meaning the result will be over 64). However in unshuffle you are looking for case input > 69. If we fix this (and similar issues with the other comparisons):
func unshuffle(input rune) rune {
    switch {
    case input > 96:
        return input - 59
    case input == 95:
        return 1
    case input > 64:
        return input - 53
    case input > 47:
        return input - 46
    default:
        return 0
    }
}

Note: The check for 95 and the default return may appear confusing. This is due to the return 50*input + 45 in Shuffle (possible inputs to this are 0 or 1, so possible outputs 45 or 95).
The test works playground. With these changes your test also passes (but it would be worth testing with random sequences - for example). Note that I'm not guaranteeing that the output is correct as I've only considered the single issue you identified.

Thanks for your input. This nearly works now. I've actually just updated the original question with your suggestions as another test case that I tried didn't work

You have not updated your Shuffle code (removing the *50 bit). Your new string works fine in my test.

Sorry I should have mentioned that the encode function has come from somewhere else, so I can't modify the shuffle func

Updated answer to reflect this. Shuffle is using a somewhat cryptic way of handling 0 and 1.
